# Convert nested list into a dictionary within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists that I would like to convert into:

```
dict[i]['name']
dict[i]['stars']
dict[i]['numrevs']
dict[i]['price']
```

`dict[0]` tells me about the first column of data (Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken)

the inner lists are as follows:

1. restaurant name (name)
2. star rating (stars)
3. number of reviews (numrevs)
4. price (price)

```
bigList = [
    ['Gus’s World Famous Fried Chicken', 'South City Kitchen - Midtown', 'Mary Mac’s Tea Room', 'Busy Bee Cafe', 'Richards’ Southern Fried', 'Greens &amp; Gravy', 'Colonnade Restaurant', 'South City Kitchen Buckhead', 'Poor Calvin’s', 'Rock’s Chicken &amp; Fries', 'Copeland’s'],
    ['4.0', '4.5', '4.0', '4.0', '4.0', '3.5', '4.0', '4.5', '4.5', '4.0', '3.5'],
    [549, 1777, 2241, 481, 108, 93, 350, 248, 1558, 67, 288],
    ['$$', '$$', '$$', '$$', '$$', '$$', '$$', '$$', '$$', '$', '$$']]
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: This is not hard.  `zip(*bigList)` will help.  What hat you tried?  This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Similar questions: [Convert list of lists to list of dictionaries](/q/35763593/4518341), [Convert list of lists to list of dictionaries based on order of items in sublist](/q/52273841/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

1. use `zip` to transpose your lists
2. call `dict` with the keys and the transposed list zipped together

then that becomes

```
keys = ["name","stars","numReviews","price"]
myDicts = [dict(zip(keys, row)) for row in zip(*bigList)]
```

this basically is just a list comprehension that does the following

```
dict([('name',"Some Name"),("stars", 5),("numReviews",50),("price","expensive")])
```

and will result in a list of the above dicts

```
[{"name":"Some Name",...},{"name":"Other name",...}, ...]
```